# AFNetworking - Store JSON results and then load them to a tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite, afnetworking

I'm getting JSON data from url with AFNetworking and storing them into a SQLite database.
Now, I want to display this info in a tableView but the point is that I want to load this data from database when the data has been downloaded. Now, my view is showing nothing because the database is empty. I have to wait for the request is completed.

These are the steps that I want to do:

1. Load tableView controller.
2. Start UIActivityIndicatorView.
3. Load data from JSON url and store them into database.
4. When finished, get this data from the database and put it into the tableView.
5. Stop the UIActivityIndicatorView.

hope you have understood me.

Thanks!!

Comment: In step 3, have you confirmed that the data has been successfully retrieved? In step 4, have you made sure to call `reloadData` when the population of the model is done? Please show us what diagnostics you've done and share relevant code snippets once you've identified precisely where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the documentation mentioned on afnetworking github page.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

You will get into this success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) function, and inside this you can reload your table data.
like

[tableoutlet reloadData];

but before reloading make sure to load your response data into sqlite db.

Tip is to fire reloadData function after getting into success function.

Comment: In the success block you will also want to deserialize the `responseObject` into an array of objects that your table view data source will populate the cells from.